# Single element assignment inside same within as entire column of data frame

Tags: r

Why is it that I can't assign a value to an entire column of a data frame, and then a single element in the same "within" statement?  The code:

```
foo <- data.frame( a=seq(1,10) )

foo <- within(foo, {
  b <- 1  # set all of b to 1
})

foo <- within(foo, {
  c <- 1  # set all of c to 1
  c[2] <- 20  # set one element to 20
  b[2] <- 20
})

foo
```

Gives:

```
    a  b  c
1   1  1  1
2   2 20 20
3   3  1  1
4   4  1 20
5   5  1  1
6   6  1 20
7   7  1  1
8   8  1 20
9   9  1  1
10 10  1 20
```

The value of b is what I expected.  The value of c is strange.  It seems to do what I expect if the assignment to the entire column (ie b <- 1) is in a different "within" statement than the assignment to a single element (ie b[2] <- 20).  But not if they're in the same "within".

Is this a bug, or something I just don't understand about R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the assignments to new columns are done as you "leave" the function. When doing

```
c <- 1
c[2] <- 20
```

all you have really created is a vector `c <- c(1, 20)`. When R has to assign this to a new column, the vector is recycled, creating the 1,20,1,20,... pattern you are seeing.

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds while I was typing another paragraph. Teaches me to be succinct :)

Comment: Ok, thanks that makes sense.  It's not quite what I expected, but it makes sense now :).

Answer (score 2):

That's an interesting one.

It has to do with the fact that `c` is defined only up to length 2, and after that the typical R "recycling rule" takes over and repeats `c` until it matches the length of the data frame. (And as an aside, this only works for whole multiples: you would not be able to replicate a vector of length 3 or 4 in a data frame of ten 10 rows.)

Recycling has its critics. I think it is an asset for a dynamically-typed interpreted language R, particularly when one wants to interactively explore data. "Expanding" data to fit a container and expression is generally a good thing -- even if it gives the odd puzzle as it does here.

Comment: Ah, that helps too.  I think i have seen the case where something like {c[3] <- 20} gives an error.